# .NET 2012 Connect to Firebird Database

Tags: vb.net, firebird

I am having trouble connecting to a Firebird Database using VB.NET 2012.  I downloaded the Firebird Entity Framework Provider through the NuGet Package Manager.

I checked and the following References have been added to the project:

EntityFramework, EntityFramework.Firebird, EntityFramework.SqlServer and FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.

When I run the program, the Output windows displays the following:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException' occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll
A first chance exception of type 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException' occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll
A first chance exception of type 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException' occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll
```

I don't get any errors displayed in the application, but nothing happens

Here is my code:

```
Imports FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

    Dim con As FbConnection
    Dim cs As FbConnectionStringBuilder

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        cs = New FbConnectionStringBuilder
        cs.Database = "C:\database.fdb"
        cs.ServerType = FbServerType.Default
        cs.UserID = "SYSDBA"
        cs.Password = "password"

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        con = New FbConnection(cs.ToString)
        con.Open()

        Dim sCmd As FbCommand
        Dim sql As String
        Dim ds As FbDataReader

        sql = "SELECT something FROM TABLE"

        sCmd = New FbCommand()
        sCmd.Connection = con
        sCmd.CommandText = sql
        ds = sCmd.ExecuteReader

        Dim str As New StringBuilder

        While (ds.Read)

            MsgBox(ds.GetString(0))

        End While

        ds.Close()

        End

    End Sub

End Class
```

I have experimented running various versions of Firebird but I really need some help.

Comment: Not sure about it, but I suggest to move away that database from the ROOT of the system disk. Usually this path requires the most elevated permissions to write there (and a database provider needs write access to the database)

Comment: You need to provide the actual exception stacktraces.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple.  Because I was using the Firebird Client the ServerType should have been set to Embedded because it includes a special client library that includes the server itself.

Answer (score -1):

Your connection string is missing hostname where the Firebird runs.

Comment: No that is not correct as I have the same code working on another Windows box.

Comment: Looking at your own answer, you should have told us you're using `Embedded`, then, obviously, you don't need a hostname.

Comment: I did state that I was using Firebird Entity Framework Provider which only works using Embedded.